# What C# Data Structure Supports The Following?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I need a C# data structure that works in the following way:

1. Define it with a static size
2. Adding new data to end of list
3. Oldest data falls off.
4. Random access of data elements

Example: If I define a structure of 5 elements and added the following

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

The data structure would look like the following:

4,5,6,7,8

I'm not sure which structure will work in this way. Vector? List? Stack? The data structure supports a static size like an array and push data that pushes off old data.

Stack/queue doesn't provide random access.
List doesn't have a "push" operation.

Perhaps a LinkedList and add custom operation for "push" that removes the first element? LinkList random access is o(n) operation though.

Comment: So make your own data structure that fits your requirements.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For maximum efficiency, that would probably be a custom class implementing a circular buffer.

Just have a fixed size array created at instantiation time to hold the data. In addition have a start index, a size member and a capacity so you know how much data is in the buffer and where it starts.

So, to start with, your list contains no data, the start position is 0 and the size is 0.

When you add an item, it goes into element `(start + size) % capacity` and `size` is incremented if it's not yet at `capacity`. If it *was* at `capacity`, you increment `start` as well, wrapping around if need be: `start = (start + 1) % capacity`.

To get an element at index `n` from the list, you actually adjust it with `start`:

```
return element[(start + n) % capacity];
```

I haven't covered removing the start of the list since that's not in your specs. However, it's a simple check to ensure `size` is not 0, then extracting the item at `element[start]`, then incrementing `start` with the same wraparound shown above.

In pseudo-code (untested but should be close):

```
def listNew (capacity):
    me = new object
    me.capacity = capacity
    me.data = new array[capacity]
    me.start = 0
    me.size = 0
    return me

def listAdd (me, item):
    if me.size = me.capacity:
        me.data[me.start] = item
        me.start = (me.start + 1) % me.capacity
    else:
        me.data[(me.start + me.size) % me.capacity] = item
        me.size = me.size + 1

def listGet (me, index):
    if index > size:
        return 0 # or raise error of some sort
    return me.data[(me.start + index) % me.capacity]

def listRemove (me):
    if size == 0:
        return 0 # or raise error of some sort
    item = me.data[(me.start + index) % me.capacity]
    me.start = (me.start + 1) % me.capacity
    me.size = me.size - 1
    return item
```

All of these operations are O(1) time complexity, as requested.

For your particular example of adding the numbers `1` through `8` to a five-element list, you would end up with:

```
  0   1   2   3   4 <--- index
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
              ^
              +--------- start    = 3
                         size     = 5
                         capacity = 5
```

That way, extracting virtual index 3 (the fourth number) from the buffer would give you an actual index of:

```
  (start + 3) % capacity
= (  3   + 3) %    5
=       6     %    5
=             1
```

Comment: Thanks. There is also the fixed statement that might be useful.

Comment: @CurtisWhite the `fixed` statement is only applicable in an unsafe context, which most definitely does not apply here. That's in the "advanced" realm of C# knowledge and only really useful when you're doing Interop/PInvoke with native (non .Net) code.

Comment: @Pax This seems to be a pretty good implementation at first glance http://www.emoticode.net/c-sharp/circular-buffer-class.html

Comment: @Curtis, yes, it's not too bad from first glance. There's no conceept of a non-full buffer (it's always considered fully populated) but that could be added reasonably easily if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a maximum-length queue (such that you must de-queue and discard one element before queuing another once it reaches the maximum length). You can do random access on a C# Queue but it's O(n) (using ElementAt LINQ extension), which presumably isn't really an issue if 5 is a typical size. If you want O(1) I suspect you'll have to roll your own (https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Collections.Generic/Queue.cs?source=cc might help!)

Answer (score 0):

Queue is the best in this situation, You should write your own wrapper class that check your count(limit) before Enqueue(Adding new data to end of list) to make it behave like a fixed one, here is an example:

```
public class FixedQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
//to sets the total number of elements that can be carried without resizing,
//we called the base constrctor that takes the capacity
    private Random random;
    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public FixedQueue(int size, Random random)
        :base(size)                 
    {
         this.Size = size;
         this.random = random;
    }

    public new void Enqueue(T element)
    {
        base.Enqueue(element);
        lock (this)
            while (base.Count > Size)
                base.Dequeue();  //as you said, "Oldest data falls off" :)
    }

    public T RandomAcess()
    {
        return this.ElementAt(random.Next(Count));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP meant by "random access", although I must admit it raised a smile :-) The random access OP is asking for means ability to access any element without having to traverse the others, _not_ the ability to access elements randomly. In any case, I think ElementAt on a queue is O(n) rather than O(1).